# How do I debug Git LFS push failures?

Tags: git, azure-devops, git-lfs, azure-repos

I have a repo I'm migrating to Azure DevOps, the repo utilizes LFS for large files. Files in LFS range from hundreds of KB to hundreds of MB. When trying to push this repo into a new repo in Azure DevOps, the push stalls at some file (i.e. `3294/8278 files`). There is no error, it just sits on that file progress for hours. The rest of the push (including pushing the repo itself) does not progress because it's blocked by this one file failure.

How could I go about identifying which file is causing the problem? Can I set LFS to show me which file it's currently trying to push? Can I only push subsets of files to narrow down which file is causing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can debug Git LFS by setting certain environment variables before you push, like so: `GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_TRANSFER_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git push REMOTE BRANCH` (where you replace `REMOTE` and `BRANCH`).  (Note that that syntax requires a POSIX shell.)

That will show the headers and the response of what's going on, which may help you troubleshoot.  Normally, though, Git LFS should upload multiple files at a time, so it shouldn't be blocked in this way.

Note that last time I checked, Azure DevOps has a bug where it doesn't handle files over a certain size (I think 128 MiB) when using HTTP/2.  This is an intentional design decision on the part of Azure Repos due to a limitation in their service, [more information about which can be found in this issue](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/4211).  You may find that that's what's going on here, in which case you can set `http.version` to `HTTP/1.1` to get things working properly.

Comment: This does indeed show a lot more information. Unfortunately, switching to HTTP/1.1 doesn't appear to solve this. I see lots of successful uploads, I suppose chunks of large files and small files. Then start to see more uploads waiting to finish. As if all the slots for uploads fill up until its waiting for all of them. Left it overnight, to no result. Seems like it should at least be timing out.
Anyway, you've answered the debugging question, and pointed me a in potential direction for ADO. Thanks.

Comment: I was able to get past this blocker by configuring two additional settings for LFS: `git config lfs.concurrenttransfers 200` and 
`git config lfs.allowincompletepush true`

Comment: I strongly recommend you don't use `lfs.allowincompletepush` because that means some of your data isn't pushed anywhere and you could end up with data loss.

Comment: Is it possible to turn it off and re-upload any incomplete files? Or do those files need to be removed then readded?

Comment: You can do `git lfs push --all` to push all files after you've turned it off.